# std::vector erasing with first iterator after last

Tags: c++, iterator, range, stdvector, std

What will happen when erasing a range whose first iterator is after the last iterator?

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2};

v.erase(
    v.begin() + 1,
    v.begin()
);
```

What about other containers?

Comment: That overload requires a valid range. `begin() + 1, begin()` is not a valid range, so you may not call that overload with those iterators.

Comment: The great thing about *undefined behavior* is that ANYTHING might happen. Could crash. Could appear to work. Might even give the expected results. Might destroy the Earth. (If the Earth is destroyed, please file a bug report with the compiler vendor. That sort of thing can result in bad reviews.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's **undefined behavior** to call `erase` with an invalid range on any container. In practice, it will generally crash the program *if you are lucky*, or smash adjacent memory if you're unlucky.

This should be true for just about *any* API that accepts an iterator range. If a range is invalid, there is no way for the underlying code/algorithm to be aware of what the stopping condition actually is.

---

Iterator ranges delimit the start and end of a range for any input or algorithm. The `end` iterator is always used to indicate the completion of that range, and must always be reachable by repeatedly incrementing the first iterator (e.g. by calling `operator++`).

Most algorithms make use of `operator!=` to detect the completion of the range, from the  [`LegacyInputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) requirement. Some ranges may optionally make use of the distance between iterators if that that range is a [`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

In either case, this detection *requires* that the first iterator be before the last, otherwise code like:

```cpp
for (auto it = first; first != last; ++first) { ... }
```

will never reach the end of the range, and similarly:

```cpp
auto distance = last - first;
```

will return an incorrect value for the distance between iterators.

Comment: Most iterative algorithms will compare iterators using `operator!=`, such algorithms will not be able to detect the case where the 1st iterator is after the 2nd iterator.  It is expected that the 1st iterator will eventually compare equal to the 2nd iterator when the iteration is finished.

Comment: It is possible to detect out of order iterators, but only if they fulfill the random access requirements because those support `operator<` which determines order. So in practice this can be done in algorithm that require random access iterators. In the case of `std::vector::erase` which only ever uses random access iterators, the inversion *could* be detected, but I don't think any implementation does. Since the situation is UB anyway, an implementation could decide to swap the iterators for you and erase correctly. It would be a bad idea though, as it would hide simple mistakes.